# Restart Amazon APL slideshow once end is reached

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to find the best method to restart my Amazon APL slideshow, I've been digging in the Alexa docs but haven't had any luck as to where to even begin. Possibly some sort of conditional logic? here's my current code.

APL

```
{
    "type": "APL",
    "version": "1.8",
    "license": "Copyright 2021 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.\nSPDX-License-Identifier: LicenseRef-.amazon.com.-AmznSL-1.0\nLicensed under the Amazon Software License  http://aws.amazon.com/asl/",
    "settings": {},
    "theme": "dark",
    "import": [],
    "resources": [],
    "styles": {},
    "onMount": [],
    "graphics": {},
    "commands":{
    },
    "layouts": {
        "WSKG-slideshow": {
            "parameters": [
                "internalIndex\n",
                "internalImageUrl"
            ],
            "items": [
                {
                    "source": "${internalImageUrl}",
                    "type": "Image",
                    "width": "100vw",
                    "height": "100vh"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "mainTemplate": {
        "parameters": [
            "payload"
        ],
        "items": [
            {
                "type": "Container",
                "width": "100vw",
                "height": "100vh",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "data": "${payload.data.properties.values}",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "type": "WSKG-slideshow",
                                "internalIndex\n": "${index}",
                                "internalImageUrl": "${data.imageUrl}"
                            }
                        ],
                        
                        "navigation": "none",
                        "onMount": [{
                        "type": "AutoPage",
                        "componentId": "WSKG-pager",
                        "duration": 1000,
                        "delay": 500
            }],
                        "type": "Pager",
                        "id": "WSKG-pager",
                        "width": "100vw",
                        "height": "100vh"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And my Data

```
{
    "data": {
        "properties": {
            "values": [
                {
                    "pageId": "1",
                    "imageUrl": "https://i.imgur.com/KT5WTJo.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "pageId": "2",
                    "imageUrl": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAoHCBYVFRgWFRYZGBgaGBgYHBoYGhgaGBoYGhgZGRgaGhocIS4lHB4rIRgYJjgmKy8xNTU1GiQ7QDs0Py40NTEBDAwMEA8QHhISHjQrJCs0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NP/AABEIAOEA4QMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAcAAABBQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAECAwUGBwj/xAA9EAACAQIDBQUGBAMIAwAAAAABAgADEQQSIQUxQVFhBnGBkaETIrHB4fAyQlLRB2JyFCMzgqKywvEWktL/xAAYAQADAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQMCBP/EACMRAQEAAgICAgMAAwAAAAAAAAABAhEhMQMSE1EiMkEUYXH/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/APHspjhDCFsRbiJIJFsw3szG9kYQ0twNDO6rvudwgAT0SNT98pXaevbN7OUvZ5KqhgRxGtjrbprrpuMxdqfw7Ni+GfNxFN9G7g27nvj0TzwLJFYXjcC9FylRWRhwYW8RzEHvEam8sWRcRLAkhHMaO0DRvFnkGEQECTzxiLxhLFEDJFtHj2kWgEs5kTHB0iAgCAjLExk1WK1rGHUSd42WOFmVYRaK8REQERnF44JiERgCv0EUXjFAI0lGpki8jhkud8lUpkGUc6JM6HsXgw+IBO5AW8t3qZzhpkTtP4ep71UkahFHmT+0Dk5de1Ygw7D4q9gd/P6zIxmhhGGcEcb890Uy1VrhwL2tsuli09nWGovkdfxoeY+Ynk3aTs7VwdQo/vIRdHA91l+RHET2HDHQceu+Tx2CTEI1GqLowOU8UbgQeBF5vtG4vn8xAzY2/sV8NWak+8aq25XU7j0+kyGW0yRXiJjBYxgDxwsZZYg1AgDKkmqySrrHaAVkyJkmjQB8ug8fjHOktyaL/T/yaF7G2PUxVQJTUnm35VHMwOM6nTLGwBJPAamdtsL+H+IrAO9qaEX978Xlwnfdl+x1HCqGID1OLsN3RRwE6VoSfZ+2unm20+waUKLPnzFQSSdB9J5u7C89t7dYkLga1/zZUHeWH1niLi8zlJtTG3Rs0V4gJBhEdqV495ALJeECPmijWigEKOhluJolbG++Dkwj2l1m0VGY851n8PsQRXdSdGQ+akEfOcmbTa7JV8uJp9Tl8wRBrHt6NjwLXktm1eFx6X+EsrJdTxgGGQZtfgT8JmzVdPFx06OmQfz38dPhClp3Ghv8RM7Dqo3WH+X5mG079/cD8iRKOfpm9qez642lbdVS5RuJB3qeht5ieOYnCMrFHFnU5ddDf9J68p7z7bIQeHPXTvBnNds+ygxNq1Gwf862/GAD67vSK8s5TXLyEJIshh+P2dUQnOpVhYODvBIuCe/nz77AQ03NtDy8RESm2skm+PlIzXG4hfHU/wDEyKmAXtoYxkmW9rXkmomwNtDuhRA5klWT9mZs7B2BUxLqiKQCdWI0AG8wCvZ+x6mJdKdJbnKuY8FB1uT43ntHZns/TwlMIguTq7nezft0hOxNiU8MgVFF7DM3FiAAPQCaRjkMxMFxNWwltWpaZ1a5YR08cd1xv8S9oAUadLi7FyOOVRYep9J5mWm32r2j/aMS7g3UHInRV0HnqfGYhWRt3VpNQ149orRrRGVoiIjEYyNliiijAcmEYapwMrySBQzbnW1qVjJYOtkdG/Syt5G8gKpuLx6ycRA49lSquUHgwuDzvrMfEtkY2G/lvjbGxAfDU7n3ggB7wJLDt73vAnlz8+UzldurGcbamy0dhcJbq1z9JrurAauSemgHlvgOCqZrDNa2oVNdOtt3iZbXqsDwudBc6k8rTU4iGXOSDO5vma6/zCxHcRqYXgKjfhve3w6ekHwtYkhalwTfKeB/l7xCmUUyCNx+B+V/jFPs7eNL8Ts2nWUiogJ0Um2pGkzqfYvD5bW/Mp8mv9980zXuL8NfTdDcPU0++IvN7Rscvj+wmHcDQiwN7cS3E9dTB27A4awGU773+U7SrU0t3SaIMtvvjAnFnsDQ1AvYMCOfUd0JqdiqLUSijLZswbiNJ1+Xie6PT4gjpAOQfsHQYLp9nh98p1WztlpRRURQAAB1MPC2tLssNDYJxBqjQ+ol4O1K8bUoBlPUffSc72vx7UMNUcH3m9xLcC28+V50uIUDQad88q/iZtAvWWip92mvvaixdwCb68BbzmMrqKxw7m8bJIlTGk9NbiWSK8bMYs0ehtLWNGDyaG5AiM2UxQ72UUC5Z2YReMq9nGyGUS9avo79ZbWXXQwRLgyTsx1tFSjsdjZ8qZGt7ovynQh6IGZ3Yniijf3kzl+zGKIAB5FfmJq4mjrcGQ3qu7Ge0n/Gum2GQ2SmqodQApJPW99fKaeBxauSr6g6jnbp3fd5hbPqALlZbrxXXQ/qU8Id7Nbggkjfcfivz7/iJvHJDPGNt3IGW+Yb1Pd1+/WMa2Ya8fQ6GDUBcHUc/HmPvjHLi5F7G9xz1E3ck9D0Nlsevwv84VgKvvd/38pmhydfqPCHYPgw38oS8s2cDcTrYg6iXU3yWHDf5zPxblTfgbfGaKJmS3EDT4zX9Z1wPdbqe6Rw+sfB6pIYM2JB5zTOhLcuMuQ6QVXu56S8vGE2SVsksV47C4gGfXNuFxPCe2So2IqMje9nYOpBvmB1Nzpae8BLk3nnu1Ox+HLvUr1cudmbKDrqbyPky1F8JNvJssYpPSU2Ns5TlRKtVuQLH4TYw3ZxXtkwCKOdR9fIXkvk+lLPt49kjimZ7eOytID36dBOii58zBauxqSf4OHVzzOg9Yr5bP4WMleMlJfhaVzPVqmwWc3elQUcuPpJL2ToDUhF/pJmfn/0dxjzv2Bino3/AIzh/wBY/wDYxofLC08ZZrRxEJK86C7NaIORJAx1i2frK1+z9Q5906LEnlOc2E1nI5idXQwwbUyGd5Xw/GHwCE7jp6ia9IZdGHceB7wZRQwgG6XEAaX8Lm0JdJ5c1eiG91K25X+HGG06WYe9Y/f3wgOGpAnUKems10REXMbLbebWErhLUsrosPhtTr53Hx3w2hRINrHp/wBzmdodraFI6Bz1Gg9dD5Rtn9vKDsA10F953eI+YlpjpK7rpMSL6H70hWBqZVseI+BgtWujgMhBB3EHf++sglTW3W3qdI/6JzG/hH8iTJZcrHrrMrCYj3zbcLDx4/AzTNUGx42v9+cZWaWgcect4RLYy4LGyovaSV5kbV2/SpPkuHf9AIuO+/GU4Hbuc2KFDyPHxGkx8mPt675amNs3G7WU5TlGtt04za2DphvaYlrkflUWUDrznX0at4PtfZiVkOZQfvjF5PHMoeOVxri07TYdBaiEHTQHzMqxHaPEke5TTxcn0Aibs8gf8K+W4QldmqDos5fjq/viyDtXHNuCL/lYwujXxJQhiC99CAQo8CZs0cKBCBQmp4ds3yMBaGJP4nQeEi6VlH4wfC86EUpL+zx/48Hy1ynta3P/AExTqv7N3R4f42I+WvnqPFaOFvKnIYXkh3SQS0QEztuRt9nUuxM6+ibTnOz2HsCec3y0587+Sk6adDFcCJp06QYDge6c7SfWdFgHBA+V/mJTx3faOc10m9AojMgAsL3sJzqYoslXE1zmWmCqL+XMBcm3MaeJndIgdLHlOJ2hs9jhsTh/zK5qL1RwBfzWx7514Y8xDLL8a8x2htB6zl3O/cOAEqwyMScoJsLmwJsBvJtuA5yiopBKkWINiDvmx2Z2i2HqNURFdijoA+qWcAMWXewtf3bi99Ta4L5t5Y6jY7O7YeiQMxyE7uTfZM9FqYi6Z1P5l3dQB5zyQ6KPOeh9n6uahbfofA2A+UllxdLTnHdbezsVezcbi467v3nRYUXAPGw9R9+c4nBPZlUb9fG+gHpedtgX90Adw8JrG7hZzTUoiZfbHapw2Eq1E/GEITobb/DfNSgJidtcOKlHKRdWDqe5lsYeTL1xtS7r51ao7vfMWdm36lixOmo1JvynrHZfE1lR6WJQrWonKwa17ZQym4Njod4M84bZdbDYhP7ssUdWQhWKuVYFd27hcXE75MXVVC1d8+IrEX3aDcAANygafvvkfLljcZZ3/G/HLbJHomz8RmC9QDNdN1pgbJoFVQHgonQINJfHpnLW2BiaIBPWQFDTSHVk96VsvKGhsKKNpMUoWqaSNRYaG1KII5p9JJKcuFOMg9ooRligHzJmk1PWWFRIMgkNu3VhFo9M3MqKESzDb9YaLddlssAILQ8QHZ34BDQOs5b2osWoeQmpgcTwuLcjMpNN2p6y1Ad/1/ebxuqxlJXbYGuLDS/WWY7ACpZgQrrex33B3qw4qZz2zsVoNw8/W950mGxIIE68MtubPHTz3tH2bBbM1Eg/qUFh5r87TmKuHWn7qKb9xE91Dhpl7QwKN+UX6ASuWdsTxkl5eLthHPvMCANd3l4TsOzmIyob6Dd36TQ2hhVX3dNdTyt+wmW623fqnJllZXXNXHUaWzTnq6aWv6mdng3sVtwPpOMwN0N+On1E6rAV7JmO/wC7TfjvCXkdKjwbbGGNRAFNiDf5aiQw9TMLw5TpK5YzKaqO9XbhNo7AxLN7i0x/Nmb/AG5fnCNidlhTf2lV/aVOHIfsJ2bJeKnSA4SePhxx6b+S60rwtC2sNC6RlEnwlmGTXU3jpT0lj2vJERBQ0SrLWEjAKzFaTAiYxhDLGj3jRB80iStIAyStOau6U5kqW+QvJp9/ZjFdXs1rqJqIkx9jkFd820USFnJ2pJSHE+Edk8POWIOvxiPh8PjHIxssOxB7vvnNrCYknjMIhuRPd9I9PFlTvset/wB5vHL1Zyx27OjWEtrV+F+G+cvS2kdLnxGnpvMLfFZh7p8ZeZSoXC7Qx9nNgNdw+sx8RTs633fLcd00kcA6wPHrcFj3D4SWfPK2HHATC4n3yTu5GdPhKmYAdJxWex6+u/fOk2JVu1/CGGXLeeHG3Z4E2AvNKk15jUauk0MPVnTHLca0bSQWSUSOfWNlJRJOdIwYSFRoBnOdZYDeKovSQQzATjR4jNBBhGkmleaAPaPIRQD5lCkbjHU8xJiOZz7dsxQzDhGvJFLxhT6/tDgWVubBqe9a86+jTJnAbPq2cd/H9p6Bs97gXPhbWYyx5K3heKcZkHXy+sMWmPvfHal084/Vj2ZrKvXyH7yJYDe7jpvPleHvhe4ekGego/MPBSfjaZs0e0aaIfzN5AfAGaKKUAAUsDvN1BHpAqVNLa5r8CbKPS8OCsLBWFuPGUxZtUVFa592yjjvMCaqXIFtN3LpNNEcneMvW/pbjE9FnJIUAAWGlr/SO47KZaZ+P7Ou9npkZl1seIPAxYLFrQstYlG5ZWIHiBOk2ZdBlbf98oTtbZiYhDoMw1BtrHfHxudt4ebV9cuvs+GcMoZTcEXBG4jpNPDi5AmHgKWRUTlwnUYClpfnrN4bvbPm1Oh67hIKsk8YLKuVZeRMa0eZaDuspIhVSUusWggpiMaMzRgzysGJmkLwCy8aRvFAPmoGLNKVqc5YrAyFjtmUWLJZL/TQDxjfD1MdVLEAfSI+x2zaFjmJ0Gtl0F+p4zrNk4wFQTpfdxmBXTIgVeOmY84URkyAndbU779B+8j7buzyxmtO2w7X595/aGBNJmbPqBkBDX675qUk+906MXNlwiaHjKzh/CHIuktFK816s+zIOFAN7XPWM9BTvGnIaTXFMG8i2GBOsPUezPprrfUaWG/7tLKNNh+Y3vvI3DoJc+GN7qfsStVcEkk39I4N7aFNN2mnzhaEgDXwgGHBO8kzSw9HXWUjCqlTJctbkPCbOHMalTEJQQ6LLLaareSsBGjM8QOTEJDNJKYA7wVxCWMGqwoVFpBmjO0rYxAmkC0ZntKzUHDygFuaKD+2ihsPm/LfcYgvP/uOU8IspmNuiwlJ33m9srD3sxHC4HU7vGYGa5AtOz2TRu6jhdQO4SHnuor4ZzUcXQvXpIRvINuFpHa1850JtoABrNfadJVx6C/5VPiby3DUA9RxxLN8TOb21pXtTsPElFA0+Q+s67DXZQSd/D5mcdgaBVNdAGI+k3MFXK2B75fxZ/aHlx+my6m/SE+0923SCU61yPOW1n0+M6ZXPYrFU/h5ybVePSDKNbmSvfoIew0Mpsd5hK674DSa3WGUiY5WaLoUxwEOpwWgtoXSE0zRNOXKJWglsZJSMUjAHk1kFEsEYM5gtUwioYFWaKtB6hlXtI9R4Iz2Mxaa2o/hB3frE9SDM5HK3OFp6W+06jyEaU+16j78IpncGng9omPARs0jE6bVtBLso5kTudiJ/er3zjtk081RehvO22Itq4H83ynL57zIrhPxtUbba2OJPAoP9IPzh2wn/vjfizfG/wA5j9ra2XGkD9SH/Ss1dltlrD+r42ks501jd41sbQwgRD1c+tzA8OTeavaNrInVifIfWY9FpXCaxRt21aT2N+OkvercATJR9YQryky1wncRD1eUtw+p1+xBqY4/H5CHYddZvG21miE36TQpU4PSXlDqR4S8iVq+isMprB04QxBNQliyVxIrHMbJ83KNeRzGTQQCayRitE0AoqNAMQ8MrmZeJeKnIorPBXf6ftGrVIEamu+SyyUkEO3GVu3hK6jcfHT71kHfje8zaek/ER4N7U9PWKZPVeJxSBeK8rpvca2w2s5PKdngTbEgcwjeYtOK2UdT4TtcM16lB/1UrHvR1/8AqcXm/Z0Y/qF7SYUnHMxHuhEI78tpdhX99W6r8IV2vbK4PNBbzN/lMjBVCAgJ1uB6mTy3lyeH6up7UOf7ocLOf9syqTzQ7Sn3aB5q3/GZdMyuPSItGhNIwNHlyPNAeh4maOGb75zNw4G87oejXOkthwlk08MeMNprA8MIcgnREaIoiGU4NShKxsrBFGEQaASEmDKg8kHgFl5FmkS8gzxhTiGmTiXmlWaZONaYyajLr1LGC5tY2KfmRKUa857VpBDvaRZhaRzC0rZze3I+nWKgsnQRRXHOKDTxcxCKKdCbT2Xv8Z3GF3Yf+mr/AL0jRTh8/brx6S7bfip/0fMzDwf5f6hFFJ/xrH9XW9o/8PD9zfBZl04opTHpBaJYkUU0bSwvDumjhuPfFFK49pZNjD/KFpFFOqIiqcJpxRRsnkRFFAHG+SMUUQRaQMUUYgerMrGcYopjJqOZ2hvg+G3x4pzXt0Tpe27zjNv/AMv7x4oUqDiiimTf/9k="
                },
                {
                    "pageId": "3",
                    "imageUrl": "https://th-thumbnailer.cdn-si-edu.com/bZAar59Bdm95b057iESytYmmAjI=/1400x1050/filters:focal(594x274:595x275)/https://tf-cmsv2-smithsonianmag-media.s3.amazonaws.com/filer/95/db/95db799b-fddf-4fde-91f3-77024442b92d/egypt_kitty_social.jpg"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally when the last image is reached the page index will reset to 1 and the whole slideshow will play again. Thanks for any direction, or any documentation!

Answer (score 0):

I have a kiosk feature that does what you suggest.  I believe you are missing some commands in the "onMount".  Here is mine:

```
    "onMount": [
    {
        "type": "Sequential",
        "repeatCount": "${card.properties.repeatCount}",
        "commands": [
            {
                "type": "SetPage",
                "componentId": "cardSlideshow",
                "value": "${card.properties.startPage}"
            },
            {
                "type": "AutoPage",
                "componentId": "cardSlideshow",
                "duration": "${card.properties.duration}",
                "delay": "${card.properties.duration}"
            },
            {
                "type": "SetPage",
                "componentId": "cardSlideshow",
                "value": 0
            }
        ]
    }
],
```

here is a link to an apl.ninja project to do this:
https://apl.ninja/BrianTarbox/slide-show-kiosk-with-auto-advance-and-speed-controls-87sx